# Special character in Perl while processing cmd

Tags: perl

```
@output_lines="pwd" ;

@value1 = q(set "a=). "@output_lines" . q(") . " & echo %a%" . "| rest.exe";
print "@value1      END\n";

print " $prog : output lines  @output_lines";
system(@value1);




#comment
o/p
set "a=pwd" & echo %a%| rest.exe
```

`rest.exe` accept NAGA  as input and it process an there is no issue in this case.

But when I pass below value as input

```
@output_lines="pwd$as$d";
```

o/p changes to:

```
set "a=pwd" & echo %a%| rest.exe
```

In this case special characters are ignored how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I was going to edit this for you, but I'm not sure where the code ends and begins, you should consider formatting your code. Each line of code should start with 4 spaces. use backticks for code within a sentence

Comment: changes are done...thank u for your valuable comments

Comment: What is in `$as` and `$d`, if they are undefined, they won't print anything

Comment: I've had a go at making your question more comprehensible, but I'm not sure that I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @user3571518 try adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script and running it. I don't think `$as` or `$d` is defined

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are not aware that a variable that starts with @ in Perl is different than a variable that starts with $. You are assigning your strings to array variables when you should be assigning them to scalars. Also, there is a difference between single quotes and double quotes. All this should be explained in the first couple of chapters of any Perl book.

Since you are not using strict and using double quotes, `"pwd$as$d"` is being interpreted as "pwd" followed by two undefined variables.

What you are probably trying to accomplish is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# ...
my $output_lines='pwd$as$d';

my $value1 = q{set "a=}.$output_lines.q{" & echo %a% | rest.exe};
print "$value1      END\n";
# assuming you defined $prog somewhere
print " $prog : output lines  $output_lines";
system($value1);
```